# Procedure for a bite from a fanged humanoid, and resulting effects

Tags: internal-consistency, humans, medicine, urban-fantasy, medical

I am currently working on a story idea involving vampire-esque fanged humans, they require blood for sustenance once or twice a month, and are willing to pay. It goes through special canals, so they can’t just use blood bags, and most humans including caregivers of donors are unaware of their existence. They do not excrete any numbing agents, and their bites hurt. They prefer much younger volunteers in order to negate some of the awkwardness. I am curious as to what safety and comfort procedures might be commonly taken, and how much it might hurt the human donor.Only willing humans are fed from, and the creatures will get into trouble for failing to use proper procedures.

I am basically asking how to turn this into a sterile, medical procedure.

Comment: Hi Amelia and Welcome to World Building Stack Exchange! Interesting question you got here but, may you please Iterate it more since as of the moment, I cannot figure out what kind of answer are you looking for? Also, I think it would be beneficial for the question for you to define how your vampire bites, are they the conventional vampires that just leave fang scare? or some morbid biting, how deep is the bite? How much flesh from the victim is removed since you asked for a procedure. Furthermore, what kind of technology level does the vampires have?

Comment: We would also like to know what technological level does your humans have. I'm sorry if this is somewhat of a very tedious task we ask you but, we would really like to help you with your story, its just that we need to ask you to define your question so that we can come up with a precise answer. Thank you and Enjoy your stay!

Comment: I upvoted your question so that you can post a question here https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6168/28224 we call this the Sandbox. People here will try to help you on developing your question, at the same time you will learn how to create a question that is acceptable in WBSO, In no time you'll be asking question that are easily understood and you will receive answers that are helpful to your story. If you may, please post a question in the Sandbox so that others could review the said question, point out what needs to be added or fixed, then proceed to post the final draft here.

Comment: **Imagine** poking your neck with a couple of ice picks.  That's what it's going to feel like to get bit by a vampire.

Comment: Note the human head is remarkable poorly designed for offensive biting, we can't open our mouths very wide, elongated canines would probably make it harder to bite not easier. pointed incisors would be better.

Comment: They would likely have that then, or a non mouth based way, they basically have bloodsucky-pokey things somewhere.

Comment: There are only a few thousand in the world, and they are a separate species capable of interbreeding with humans.

Comment: @Mr.J The reputation requirement to [participate in meta](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta) has been lowered to 1, precisely so that new users can use the sandbox. See also [Please lower the reputation requirement to participate on WB.SE Meta](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6519/29). Also, please vote based on post quality, not based on whether the user is new or not. Posts should be voted on based on their merits, not based on who posted them or the poster's previous contributions to the site.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Yep, I removed my vote now. Now that I could remove it. And will not upvote questions since as I have read, you just need 1 reputation for sandbox. Thank you for the reminders.

Comment: Please do not make edits that invalidate existing answers. If an edit would do so, open up a new question instead.

Comment: Renan, I did not invalidate any previous wanders, I took the same information and re worded it so that it was more clear, the previous awnser is still valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you changed quite a lot of you question and I can see my previous answer does not meet your needs. I'll leave it there regardless as I'll answer a completely different thing here. If you find the first answer unhelpful, tell me and I'll delete it.

First, how to chose the site for biting. You need a large amount of blood to pass through relatively surface level arteries. Neck, femoral region in the thighs, near the armpit by the axillary artery, by the elbow in the proximal region of the forearm, also the the distal portion of the forearm by the wrist. Be aware of other structures when choosing the site as a untrained bitter may cause other kinds of injuries. Think of nerves that tend to go with the arteries, ligaments and even bones if you bite too hard. If you damage any of these, the blood donor may not want to donate again or even die. Also, there's more risk of infection in the femoral site as it's near the pelvis and genital organs. It' more difficult to get hemostasis on the neck due to higher flow of blood and it's harder and more dangerous to compress if needed. Peripheral sites should be preferred to the donor, even cheaper if you want to put a price on it. Higher flow and more dangerous sites should cost more due to the risk of death and damage.

You should disinfect the site as in a surgery, using iodine and high percentage alcohol. The lips and surrounding skin of the biter should also be disinfected. That would be the antiseptic method. You can't do that to the inner mouth, thus you would need other method of prophylaxis. Just as some people with heart disease need to take a dose of antibiotics prior to any dental procedure, the biter should take this dose 1 hour before the biting is done, also, it' safer if the donor take one as well. Anesthetics are a must if you want a painless experience. Local anesthetics are just fine but might give the bite a strange taste. If the vampire want a cleaner taste skip it, if he likes to know that his victims/donors feels pain. A painful experience should cost more.

You can safely suck around 450-500 ml of blood every 3 months, giving he's health and has more than 60-70 kg.

The biter should be taught how to bite, in order not to cause any laceration or bigger trauma than its needed and try to pin point that desired artery, guaranteeing that the human will not die due to excess bleeding. There should be a medical team attending all biting session and having the authority to call it of if anything goes bad.

After the session, if the vampire transmits any disease, the donor has to take de serum or it should be checked first if his vaccine is on point. Also, some vampires might be prohibited to take the blood if they fail any medical test that show infection in high levels. The human must be fed well after the bite and need to get some rest after it for a day or more.

If the vampire is rich enough and want that nice and "flowy" blood, he can pay top price to a human who uses heparin first, as it'll be "thinning" the blood and preventing it to clot fast and the need of re-biting. Also if the human feed on high fat food prior to donating, his blood might be milkier and tastier, depending on the taste of the customer.

That's all I have again.

Comment: Sorry about the changes, I meant the same thing but worded it poorly. Your other comment is still great.

Comment: No problem at all, you'll get the hang of it. Welcome and glad I could help,

Comment: Also just a bit I worked out that you might be interested in, while you can’t disinfect the inner moth with the same methods as the Outer, you can still basically Baruch the teeth with a high proof alcohol.

Answer (score 8):

I'll add more on the medical side.

Bites are an important medical urgency, even emergency some times. All of them need steady cleaning and decontamination as to prevent infection. The longer the time between disinfection and the bite, bigger is the risk of infection.

If there's a high risk of infection, it' best not to suture the wound and let it heal as second intention, thus leaving a bigger scar and more deformity. Although there are some controversies, if it's a low risk of infection wound, after the decontamination you can repair the tissue by suturing it. The larger the damage, more complex and nuanced is the treatment. You can have abrasion, lacerations, tissue avulsion and a variety of damages to the skin.

Human bites tend to infect more than other common animals, so antibiotics is a must in this case. Be mindful of other diseases as rabies and tetanus. The first is transmitted by any animal who's infected and the latter requires profilaxy(measures to avoid) in all cases of open skin trauma. Also, cat bites can lead to a
Sporotrichosis, so your vampire might transmit his own disease as you design it. Maybe after sometime people will study this disease and find a serum for it and thus create a protocol for vampire bites.

In every health system there are compulsory notifications of some diseases, and rabies is one of them. Every suspect bite, at least in my country, needs to be notified to the health department and the case is followed until completion, either the pacient contracts it or he heals. People will look into those weird and different bites and will start to wonder where all those symptons are coming from and governmental measures will be taken.

That's all i can think of now, hope this helps.